# Displaying a page in Firefox without opening a new tab

Tags: firefox, url

I'm writing an editor that is updating a WYSIWYG view in the browser. As this update can happen often i don't want to open the page in a new tab. Is there any way other then using the ugly way of emitting keystrokes to enter the Open URL command and entering the URL (I'm doing this right now, but it's buggy if the user interacts with the system in the meantime).

I tag this as firefox but comments on other browsers are welcome.

Comment: What context is this in?

Answer (score 0):

Script given below changes location without opening new tab. I think it would be helpful.

TYPE IN ADDRESS BAR:

```
javascript:window.location.href = "http://www.yahoo.com";
```

Comment: But i want to do this from an external program not from within a page

Comment: Ooops!! Then you can ask for an alternative to this JavaScript in whatever language you are using for the code.